# recipient timezone not working when sending a push notification for AUS, US and Europe

Tags: android, ios, push-notification, timezone

The problem we would like to understand and work around is delivering push notifications to players that are in different timezones and regions, all at the same local time. It would appear the recipient timezone option is not working when setting up a recipient timezone push notification.

We run time based campaigns in our products and send push notifications to engage our players, however as the players are scattered across the globe there is not one suitable time that covers all locations for the Push to be delivered to everyone. We use Firebase for iOS and Android push notifications.

When testing on a single device we never receive a Push notification when we have set it up using the recipient timezone option. When using the recipient timezone option to send a live push notification we have had negative feedback that they have been received outside of the expected time.

There are a few things I would like to understand:
Is there a problem with the recipient timezone option?
Are we testing it incorrectly, when trying just a single device?

Are there any other ways that we can set up a push notification to reach all players at the same local time for them. (9am Australia, 9am GMT, 9am US)?
Thanks for your help and look forward to hearing back.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a date that should be suitable for all time zone .

For example : If you put date 07/04/2018 at 5:00 pm and in one country this time has passed , then you should increase your time to be 10:00 pm for example . It will work because this time hasn't come yet .

I hope my answer is the answer that you want .